# How can I get netflix-desktop to remember window settings (or at least not start in full screen)

Tags: 12.04, wine, kubuntu, fullscreen, netflix

This is a fairly petty thing. I have installed netflix-desktop and it runs well. I would just like it to remember the window settings from my last session or, failing that, not start in full screen. I am aware that I can just hit F11 and drop out of fullscreen. Like I said, I know this is petty.

Here is what the netflix-desktop startup script looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Enable translation capabilities
. gettext.sh
export TEXTDOMAIN="netflix-desktop";
export TEXTDOMAINDIR="/usr/share/locale";
# General strings that are translatable
gettext_service_name=`gettext "Netflix Desktop"`;

WINE_BROWSER="/usr/bin/wine-browser";

PACKAGE="netflix-desktop" DEPENDENCIES="wine-silverlight5.1-installer" SERVICE="${gettext_service_name}" URL="http://www.netflix.com/" "${WINE_BROWSER}" $*;
```

It seems like there should be some parameter that I can pass to wine-browser, but I don't know what it is.

Here is a copy of the relevant .wine-browser/profile-settings

```
# Wine Browser profile settings (do not edit)
EXTENSION_INSTALLED=1;
CLIENT_SIDE_GRAPHICS_WORKAROUND=0;
BROWSER_USER_AGENT_WORKAROUND=1;
BROWSER_KATSOMO_WORKAROUND=1;
BROWSER_SECURITY_WORKAROUND=1;
```

Finally, here is the prefs.js which may be where the setting is although there is nothing really obvious to me:

```
# Mozilla User Preferences
user_pref("app.update.enabled", false);
user_pref("app.update.lastUpdateTime.addon-background-update-timer", 1384276497);
user_pref("app.update.lastUpdateTime.background-update-timer", 1384276377);
user_pref("app.update.lastUpdateTime.blocklist-background-update-timer", 1384276617);
user_pref("app.update.lastUpdateTime.browser-cleanup-thumbnails", 1366324221);
user_pref("app.update.lastUpdateTime.search-engine-update-timer", 1351628024);
user_pref("browser.bookmarks.restore_default_bookmarks", false);
user_pref("browser.cache.disk.capacity", 358400);
user_pref("browser.cache.disk.smart_size.first_run", false);
user_pref("browser.cache.disk.smart_size.use_old_max", false);
user_pref("browser.cache.disk.smart_size_cached_value", 358400);
user_pref("browser.download.panel.firstSessionCompleted", true);
user_pref("browser.migration.version", 10);
user_pref("browser.pagethumbnails.storage_version", 3);
user_pref("browser.places.smartBookmarksVersion", 4);
user_pref("browser.rights.3.shown", true);
user_pref("browser.shell.checkDefaultBrowser", false);
user_pref("browser.slowStartup.averageTime", 0);
user_pref("browser.slowStartup.samples", 0);
user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://www.netflix.com/");
user_pref("browser.startup.homepage_override.buildID", "20120713134347");
user_pref("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "14.0.1");
user_pref("browser.tabs.autoHide", true);
user_pref("datareporting.healthreport.nextDataSubmissionTime", "1384336720649");
user_pref("datareporting.healthreport.service.firstRun", true);
user_pref("datareporting.policy.firstRunTime", "1384250320649");
user_pref("datareporting.sessions.current.activeTicks", 10);
user_pref("datareporting.sessions.current.clean", true);
user_pref("datareporting.sessions.current.firstPaint", 1299);
user_pref("datareporting.sessions.current.main", 169);
user_pref("datareporting.sessions.current.sessionRestored", 1342);
user_pref("datareporting.sessions.current.startTime", "1384276822856");
user_pref("datareporting.sessions.current.totalTime", 70);
user_pref("datareporting.sessions.currentIndex", 5);
user_pref("datareporting.sessions.previous.0", "{\"s\":1384250318545,\"a\":11,\"t\":58,\"c\":true,\"m\":219,\"fp\":787,\"sr\":3324}");
user_pref("datareporting.sessions.previous.1", "{\"s\":1384250448283,\"a\":5,\"t\":47,\"c\":true,\"m\":221,\"fp\":1135,\"sr\":1176}");
user_pref("datareporting.sessions.previous.2", "{\"s\":1384276184319,\"a\":11,\"t\":69,\"c\":true,\"m\":331,\"fp\":1541,\"sr\":1588}");
user_pref("datareporting.sessions.previous.3", "{\"s\":1384276256520,\"a\":92,\"t\":461,\"c\":true,\"m\":256,\"fp\":1398,\"sr\":1441}");
user_pref("datareporting.sessions.previous.4", "{\"s\":1384276759544,\"a\":3,\"t\":12,\"c\":true,\"m\":262,\"fp\":1412,\"sr\":1453}");
user_pref("distribution.mozilla13.bookmarksProcessed", true);
user_pref("dom.ipc.plugins.processLaunchTimeoutSecs", 1);
user_pref("dom.ipc.plugins.timeoutSecs", 2);
user_pref("extensions.blocklist.enabled", false);
user_pref("extensions.blocklist.pingCountVersion", -1);
user_pref("extensions.bootstrappedAddons", "{}");
user_pref("extensions.databaseSchema", 14);
user_pref("extensions.enabledAddons", "%7B66e634b8-39da-11e2-bccc-0090f5c75ad5%7D:0.3.0,%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D:22.0");
user_pref("extensions.installCache", "[{\"name\":\"app-global\",\"addons\":{\"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}\":{\"descriptor\":\"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Mozilla Firefox\\\\browser\\\\extensions\\\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}\",\"mtime\":1384250292747,\"rdfTime\":1371557659000}}},{\"name\":\"app-profile\",\"addons\":{\"{66e634b8-39da-11e2-bccc-0090f5c75ad5}\":{\"descriptor\":\"Z:\\\\usr\\\\share\\\\wine-browser-installer\\\\fullscreen-close-plugin\",\"mtime\":1384250116775,\"rdfTime\":1381803141000}}}]");
user_pref("extensions.lastAppVersion", "22.0");
user_pref("extensions.lastPlatformVersion", "22.0");
user_pref("extensions.pendingOperations", false);
user_pref("extensions.shownSelectionUI", true);
user_pref("gecko.buildID", "20130618035212");
user_pref("gecko.mstone", "22.0");
user_pref("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0");
user_pref("intl.charsetmenu.browser.cache", "UTF-8");
user_pref("network.cookie.prefsMigrated", true);
user_pref("pdfjs.migrationVersion", 1);
user_pref("pdfjs.previousHandler.alwaysAskBeforeHandling", true);
user_pref("places.history.expiration.transient_current_max_pages", 104858);
user_pref("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/pdf");
user_pref("plugin.importedState", true);
user_pref("privacy.sanitize.migrateFx3Prefs", true);
user_pref("signon.rememberSignons", false);
user_pref("toolkit.startup.last_success", 1384276823);
user_pref("toolkit.telemetry.previousBuildID", "20130618035212");
user_pref("toolkit.telemetry.prompted", 2);
user_pref("toolkit.telemetry.rejected", true);
user_pref("urlclassifier.keyupdatetime.https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/newkey", 1386842323);
user_pref("xpinstall.whitelist.add", "");
user_pref("xpinstall.whitelist.add.180", "");
user_pref("xpinstall.whitelist.add.36", "");
```

I've tried googling for common sense keywords, but haven't found anything helpful. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't petty, I've been trying to do this for over a year.
I finally found the command line option to start wine-browser in windowed mode instead of full screen.  It's `--windowed`.  Change the last line of `/usr/bin/netflix-desktop` to

```
PACKAGE="netflix-desktop" DEPENDENCIES="wine-silverlight5.1-installer" SERVICE="${gettext_service_name}" URL="http://www.netflix.com/" "${WINE_BROWSER}" --windowed $*;
```

Now if I can figure out how to keep the cursor from disappearing behind the player it will work perfectly.

Comment: I don't have the karma to upvote _and_ mark this as answered, so please know that I am very grateful for your answer.

Comment: `netflix-desktop` passes the commandline arguments to `wine-browser` so perhaps a better solution is to change the `Exec` statement in `/usr/share/applications/netflix-desktop.desktop` to `netflix-desktop --windowed`.  Or setup another launcher.